# Ejecutar .exe incluido dentro de un proyecto PHP

Tags: php

Es posible ejecutar un archivo .exe incluido dentro del directorio de un proyecto PHP, si se puede ejecutar como puedo ver el resultado del mismo en una pagina PHP.

Comment: Puedes ejecutarlo llamando la función [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)  de `PHP`, te dejo la documentación para que la revises.

Comment: Se puede ejecutar un .exe y mostrar los resultados en una pagina .PHP? @Andrés

Comment: Cuando dices mostrar resultado a que te refieres?, porque el `exe` si se puede ejecutar siempre y cuando tengas privilegios en el servidor.

Comment: Esa es la pregunta, _como puedo ver el resultado del mismo en una pagina PHP._ @Andrés Me interesa eso

Comment: si te refieres a que el programa se abra en el navegador o algo por el estilo, la respuesta es no, si te refieres a que muestre lo que tiene el programa, también la respuesta es no, por eso te preguntaba que fueras mas especifico cuando dices **resultado**  ya que pueden significar muchas cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu aplicación PHP corre en un servidor windows sí se puede ejecutar un archivo .exe, si este .exe retorna alguna información también puedes mostrarla como texto en php usando la función [shell_exec()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php) que **ejecuta un comando mediante el intérprete de comandos y devuelve la salida completa como una cadena**

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$salida = shell_exec('abc.exe'); //Si el archivo abc.exe esta en el mismo directorio que el script PHP, sino poner la ruta completa del archivo
echo "<pre>$salida</pre>";
?>
```